# Can this regular expression be done better?

Tags: regex

I am attempting to only limit a particular denomination of a domain but allow others. For example the regular expression is

```
^(www\.)?(?!abc\.co)[a-zA-Z\-]+\.(co|org)\.uk$
```

This would disallow abc.co.uk and www.abc.co.uk but allow www.abcdef.co.uk, www.abc-def.co.uk, etc however am wondering if this can be done better?

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the same regex allowing sub-domains.

```
^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z\-]+\.)?(?!abc\.co)[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+\.(co|org)\.uk$
```

Comment: What specifically are the requirements for what you want to allow and reject?

Comment: Use `/i` or `(?i:...)`, since I'm guessing you don't want to allow `abC.co.uk`.

Comment: @Gareth - I wish to allow every domain variation except for abc.co.uk

Comment: @Qtax - No regardless of whether it is case-insensitive abc.co.uk should not be allowed.

Comment: @Monkey, "no"? You do not agree that it should be case-insensitive?

Comment: So you want to allow `child.abc.co.uk` or `child.abc-def.co.uk` ?

Comment: @Monday, those do not match his current expression, but if he does want to allow subdomains, what about `abc.computer.co.uk`?

Comment: The requirements seem vaguely...

Comment: @Qtax - I agree that it should be case-insensitive.

Comment: @Monday - The requirements are not vague as I have specifically stated that it should disallow abc.co.uk and www.abc.co.uk but not any other permutation. I have not allowed for sub-domains but that can be easily extended. My question is for the purposes of a domain i.e. not sub-domain, is the regular expression the best way to validate.

Comment: Why don't you compare the two particular urls?

Comment: @Monday - What do you mean exactly?

Comment: `if(str == "abc.co.uk" || str == "www.abc.co.uk"){return false;}`

Comment: @Monday - Unfortunately I can't implement this programmatically as the redirects occur at a server level.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to match anything the *doesn't* end with `abc.co.uk` or `abc.org.uk`.
Assuming that to be correct, here's the regex that expresses that:

```
(?<!abc.(co|org).uk)$
```

This uses a negative look behind from the end of the input to assert it doesn't end with the given regex.

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you would do a negative lookbehind as opposed to a negative lookahead?

Comment: Because the significant thing is the input should not *end* with this, so using the end of input as an anchor, this regex says "when you get to the end, check the previous chars aren't blah blah".

Comment: Thanks. But I would thought you would want to check whether it starts with the string for example abc.co.uk and if it does do not execute the rest of the expression

Tried your suggestion at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it does not seem to work.